# Got a plant as a present. What kind of plant is it?

Tags: identification, watering, sunlight

I got a plant as a present. What is the name of this plant? How often should I water this plant? Does this plant like sunlight?

[image: Image of a plant with deep green, paddle or teardrop shaped leaves sitting in a bot by a window. Approximately 10 inches high.]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community I know absolutely nothing about plant so I have 0 information I can provide unfortunately. I don't even know what is the name of the plant..

Comment: You could ask the person who gave it to you, most efficiently. As for here, you might [edit] your question down to what it is, which may well provide enough information to answer your other questions. Does the pot it's in have no holes for drainage? That's a common problem with gift plants, that helps to kill them. Non-specifically, it looks like some type of succulent, which generally goes with "infrequent watering, but that can be submerging the pot for 20-30 minutes and then letting it drain" - **if** it has drain holes. If not, repot it into a pot with drain holes.

Comment: The Q&A format works better with one question per question, and linking related ones, rather than multiple questions as one question. Take the [tour] to learn more about how this place is a bit different than most "forums"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What a handsome plant!

I believe this is a *[Clusia rosea](https://landscapeplants.aub.edu.lb/Plants/GetPDF/d7b81c00-9396-424b-a3a3-b305045c1a0a)* (AKA Autograph Tree) based on:

- Opposing, dark green simple leaves
- Leathery leaves with smooth edges
- Pinnate leaf venation
- Obovate / teardrop shaped leaves

An internet search for "clusia rosea houseplant care" will tell you everything you need to know to care for it, but a few highlights:

- It is invasive in Hawaii and other parts of the world
- It is toxic to pets and humans if ingested, including the fruit
- It needs well drained soil - if that pot doesn't have drainage holes, it isn't suitable for the plant
- It likes sunlight, warmth, and humidity
- It's called an Autograph tree because damage to the leaves will scar for the leaf's life, so you can write on it.

[image: A single leaf from an Autograph Tree, showing the name 'Bill' signed on the leaf]

Comment: To me  the leaves dont quite match up.

Comment: @RohitGupta I've added what made me believe it's an Autograph Plant to the answer.  The leaf shape in OP's picture is a bit more elongated than most of the examples I see online, but I do see examples with leaves as long as OP's.

Comment: Thats a much better answer +1